# having a string as dict and formatting it through eval (not subscriptable)

Tags: python, dictionary, set, eval, typeerror

I never used this kind of command so this error makes me raise an eybrow.
I'm trying to refactor my code so instead of an output like

```
'temp': 22,56, 'temp_max': 25.6, 'temp_min': 19.0, 'temp_kf': None
```

it shows simply `22,56`.
I found a code that said to us a `dict`:

```
s = "'temp': 18.72, 'temp_max': 20.0, 'temp_min': 17.0, 'temp_kf': None"
data = eval('{{{}}}'.format(s))
temperature1 = str(data['temp'])
print(temperature1)
```

where the output comes out like `18,72`

So i tried to put my variable `t` as a string (which if printed gives the same exact output as the dict inside of s, only with current temperature numbers) inside of `s`.:

```
s = str(t))
data = eval('{{{}}}'.format(s))
temperature1 = str(data['temp'])
print(temperature1)
```

And this tells me s is unhashable, so i modified it in `s = hash(str(t))`

And now I get the error

```
TypeError: 'set' object is not subscriptable
```

Why is this so difficutlt?

Comment: Your desired output is just `22, 56`?

Comment: Yes, basically the first temperature contained inside of t

Comment: Where did your `s` string come from in the first place? You should change the code that produces `s` rather than trying to post-process `s`, if at all possible.

Comment: @user2357112 well I have no idea whatsoever, I thought I could provide t instead of S but that doesen't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue here is how you set up your dictionary, you actually only created a `string` that resembles a dictionary, take a look at this and then also look back at some other reference sources for the proper structure of a dictionary

**Solution**

```
dicta = {
    'temp': '22, 56', 'temp_max': 25.6, 'temp_min': 19.0, 'temp_kf': None
}

print(dicta['temp'])
```

**Output**

> ```
> (xenial)vash@localhost:~/python$ python3.7 split.py 
> 22, 56
> ```

You can pretty it up with some labeling like so

```
print(f"Temp: {dicta['temp']}")
```

This prints:

> ```
> (xenial)vash@localhost:~/python$ python3.7 split.py 
> Temp: 22, 56
> ```

Comment: Yes sir if this was the response you were looking for helps me if you could confirm the answer, and also prevents others from working on a solution to a solved problem! Cheers!